# How to select direct child with use XPath lxml Python?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, python-3.5

I am doing some lxml code but not understand what is difference between - I want to select child directly below parent:

```
 xml = '<parent><child></child><parent>'
 root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)

 root.xpath('child')
```

and './child':

```
 root.xpath('child')
```

Answer (score 3):

In this situation, the expressions `child` and `./child` give the same results. This is because `child` implicitly assumes a *context node*, which in XPath is referred to as `.`. To see what the context node is in Python / lxml / your document, simply evaluate `.`. After correcting a typo in your XML document which would have led to a well-formedness error:

```
>>> xml = '<parent><child></child></parent>'
>>> root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
>>> root.xpath('.')
[<Element parent at 0x1038446c8>]
```

As you can see, the `parent` element is the implicit context of any XPath expression that is evaluated against this document.

But `./` can not always be omitted from an expression, there are scenarios where it is necessary. For instance, if you want to search for all descendants of an element other than the context node, you would use `.//descendant` and `//descendant` would probably lead to wrong results.

As an example, imagine you would like to find an element `other` if it is a descendant of the `child` element, but not otherwise. Your document could look like:

```
>>> xml = '<parent><other find="no"/><child><other find="yes"/></child></parent>'
>>> root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
```

And you would first look for the `child` element:

```
>>> child = root.xpath('child')[0]
```

Then evaluate XPath expressions using this element as the context:

```
>>> child.xpath('//other')
[<Element other at 0x1038446c8>, <Element other at 0x105380348>]
>>> child.xpath('.//other')
[<Element other at 0x105380348>]
```

and in this case, a `.` at the beginning of an XPath expression actually has an impact on the list of results, only `.//other` returns the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

when you select element without axes, it's Abbreviated Syntax :

```
child::the_element
```

is equal to

```
the_element
```

**Current context**

An expression prefixed with a period and forward slash (./) explicitly uses the current context as the context. For example, the following expression refers to all  elements within the current context:

```
./author
```

Note that this is equivalent to the following:

```
author
```